# Anchor Tag's On Click Event is Firing, but Default is not

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

I have an anchor tag wrapped around a radio input. When I click on them, the radio button gets checked, but the anchor tag does not do anything.

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
  <input type="radio" />
</a>
```

I tried adding an onclick handler to the anchor tag to see if it was being clicked and it worked as expected:

```
<a onclick="console.log('anchor clicked');" href="https://stackoverflow.com">
  <input type="radio" />
</a>
```

This also showed me that the anchor tag was being clicked twice so I added event.stopPropagation to the input tag:

```
<a onclick="console.log('anchor clicked');" href="https://stackoverflow.com">
  <input onclick="event.stopPropagation();" type="radio" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's invalid html5. Per [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), the content model of the `a` element states that it can not have interactive content a descendant. A non-hidden `input` is interactive content.

Comment: I'm setting it's display to 'none' in css.

Comment: @epiqueras read the link. a non-hidden `input` is `type=hidden`

Comment: Correct answer, but I think you mean "a non-hidden `input` is *anything except* `type=hidden`"

Comment: @RickHitchcock oops! thanks, yeah that's what I meant.